# SearchServiceApplication::GetQueryHealthMonitoringSettings--Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search

In a sharepoint 2013 farm i found below error in uls logs and unable to delete  Search Administration Web Service Application and search service application status is stopped

> SearchServiceApplication::GetQueryHealthMonitoringSettings--Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.IntegerSearchSetting.GetConfigParameter()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchSetting.GetSetting(String
>   name, List`1 searchSettings)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.GetQueryHealthMonitoringSettings(String
>   component)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the Search Service Application and Proxy (use -Force if necessary). This action will remove the dependent Search Admin Web Service.